# Problema con javax.xml en OpenJDK 11 y Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Tengo un proyecto Maven en OpenJDK 11 y Eclipse 2019-12, el cual anteriormente con Win7 era totalmente funcional. Actualicé a Win10 y una vez volví a montarlo pasa lo siguiente:

Me aparece el error siguiente:

"The package javax.xml.transform.stream is accessible from more than one module: unnamed, java.xml"
"The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: unnamed, java.xml"

Intento solucionarlo entrando en Properties/Java Build Path y removiendo el módulo java.xml.
Se solucionan los problemas anteriores, pero ahora aparecen los siguientes:

"The import org.w3c.dom.CDATASection cannot be resolved"
"The import javax.xml.transform cannot be resolved"

Si vuelvo a añadir el módulo, se arregla lo anterior pero aparecen los primeros errores que he puesto. Ya no sé qué hacer.

No tengo la menor idea de por qué ahora tengo estos problemas que antes no tenía, no sé si es problema de Eclipse o de qué, y la verdad es bastante frustrante.

¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo solucionar esto?

Muchas gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es de Eclipse, lo que te ocurre es un problema con los módulos de Java.
Creo que tu problema es que tienes un **classpath** y un **modulepath** en tu proyecto a la vez, lo que causa conflictos:

- Si no añades un fichero `module-info.java` a tu proyecto, éste será parte del módulo `unnamed` (sin nombre). y podrá ver (importar) todo el código de este módulo, más el código en el módulo [`java.base`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.base-summary.html) (lo que podríamos decir es que son los paquetes básicos de JavaSE) más el módulo raíz `java.se`, que es la manera de tener un comportamiento similar a lo que era Java 8:

  ```
  module java.se {
      requires transitive java.desktop;
      requires transitive java.security.jgss;
      requires transitive java.security.sasl;
      requires transitive java.management;
      requires transitive java.logging;
      requires transitive java.datatransfer;
      requires transitive java.sql.rowset;
      requires transitive java.compiler;
      requires transitive java.sql;
      requires transitive java.naming;
      requires transitive java.prefs;
      requires transitive java.rmi;
      requires transitive java.xml.crypto;
      requires transitive java.management.rmi;
      requires transitive java.xml;
      requires transitive java.scripting;
      requires transitive java.instrument;
  }
  ```

  Esto significa que debes usar el classpath para añadir librerías y todo funciona como en Java 8.
- Si tienes un fichero `module-info.java` en tu proyecto, entonces el proyecto estará en el módulo declarado (con un nombre) y sólo verás el código que está en `java.base` más el código que hayas declarado como requerido en tu declaración de módulo. Como los módulos con nombre (tu proyecto) sólo se ven a a través del modulepath , tienes que poner tus dependencias (ficheros jar) en el **classpath**, especialmente si son ficheros JAR compatibles con Java 8 y anteriores. Java crea automáticamente para cada dependencia un módulo **usando el nombre del JAR como nombre del módulo**.

Usando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> en Eclipse deberías poder buscar los recursos (clases) que están duplicadas y el origen de cada una. Seguramente estás usando el módulo raíz java.se y además importando el módulo java.xml por otro lado.